# Barred from former work premises. What can I do?

Tags: professionalism, united-kingdom, reputation

So I worked at my previous job (in a pub. Bar and kitchen) for 2yrs. No issues. Found another job with better hours, handed in my notice, worked it and then started with my current employer. About 6months ago.
Beginning of December I got told that I was banned (from the previous place)for something another member of staff had done but had blamed it on me.
Approached the pub manager to discuss this. Was rudely told to leave and was given no information or explanation.

Tried again a week later (again, at the previous employer where I've been meeting friends, been drinking and socialising in this pub for years) Again left with no explanation dismissive attitude and unnecessary rudeness. 
Now I've been informed by a doorman that I'm not allowed in or near the building ask the manager told him I'd been dismissed! 
I'm fuming!

What's going on here!? Is there aything I can do? Technically defamation of character is slander. And his attitude towards me haS been disgusting. I'm not prepared to let him get away with it!

Comment: Do you have proof of your innocence? Do you want to bring in the law and declare war that may make it difficult for you to get another job? Consider carefully what you are prepared to do over that something as while you may say it is defamation, do you have proof to support this or is it merely your word and this could quickly become a "He said/she said" debate.

Comment: I can't tell from this description: were you banned from the pub where you used to work and still hang out, or were you fired in a roundabout way from the new one?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the workplace.

Comment: It is , however, about the ex-workplace

Answer (score 9):

While getting barred from a former place of employment (unfairly or not) is an unfortunate side-effect of leaving far too commonly, you don't have to accept being treated unfairly.

One option would be to go over your former manager's head. Speak to the owners - either the licencee or the brewery. They have no obligation to actually listen, the manager of a pub has pretty much final say about who is allowed in or not for whatever reason they choose. But you could explain the situation, be fair and honest in what you say, point out that you've been a customer longer than you were a member of staff and that you feel you have been barred unfairly and unnecessarily.

Of course, there still the "do you really want to continue frequenting a place like this?" question. Is it worth the aggravation?

Comment: This is then route I've taken. Thank you. It's more about principle than anything else. But no. Rightly said. I do not want the hassle from that place any longer.

Answer (score 6):

That's internal politics. It happens. Sometimes, someone has personal objectives, and you happen to be in the path. So you get shot out. It's nothing personal, just politics.

Unless you want to play politics to a deep level, the only thing to do is forget the place and look elsewhere. The world is big enough for both the guy who made you kicked out(not always easy to know who exactly) and for yourself.

Comment: Well complaints to the brewery's area management and to the licencing committee might be worth considering

Comment: I mean "office politics", not state-level politics. Manoeuvers of power. Assuming the OP is right in that he made a good job, then the usual reason for firing such people(and even forbidding them to be customers) is purely relational. The basis for office politics.

Answer (score 3):

Put it down to experience, there's not much else you can do.

At the end of the day, you lost your job for whatever reason and you have sour grapes, you need to move forwards not obsess over it. Some people in a position of power are rude when they get the chance, especially if they have a doorman between them and you. As an ex bouncer myself I have been in the position of stopping former staff from coming in. It's better for all concerned if they just don't make trouble, because they will be physically ejected if need be, and could even be arrested.

It's not all that uncommon in that industry. So unless you're confident that you can physically take care of yourself, just move on.

Comment: I'd upvote the sentiment except for the unless. Force is the last refuge if the incompetent, and isn't even woth considering here.

Comment: @keshlam I'm guessing you have absolutely no idea about that industry? We've all read Isaac Asimov. I'm not advocating the OP uses force, he/she doesn't seem capable, but it's what they need to watch out for if they keep pushing. Doorman use force sometimes, it's part of their job.

Comment: I have no interest in that industry, but I also consider challenging a bouncer or doorman physically  to be an exercise in pure stupidity. There's absolutely nothing to be gsined from doing so that is worth having,  My objection stands. Scratch the "unless" clause, and just move on.

Comment: suit yourself, I went straight through a bouncer to collect my gear when told I couldn't, and I spent years in that industry. It was either that or lose a few hundred worth of clothing that was in my locker

Comment: It might have worked, but was still the wrong answer, in my opinion. As you say, suit yerself ("and suture them thereafter"?)

Comment: ahaha... got to remember that line (Y)

Comment: The OP hasn't lost their job. They just got barred from their previous place of work.

Comment: @kilisi I doubt that EVERYONE here has read Foundation by any stretch. Don't ruin a cute inside joke. :-)

Comment: @Jay ahaha... true that... damn good books :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Now I've been informed by a doorman that I'm not allowed in or near the building ask the manager told him I'd been dismissed! I'm fuming! What's going on here!? Is there aything I can do?

I don't think you can do anything in regard to being banned from an establishment unless they did so for protected reasons. In America, for example, a store cannot ban you because of your race. In the UK that might be different so check into that.

However, you might want to speak to a lawyer in regard to the manager saying you've been dismissed/fired when you did not. If you indeed quit after you put your notice in, that might affect your future job hunts should they call this employer and the manager says you were dismissed for reasons you don't know.